# How to forward a request to other endpoint in node.js

Tags: node.js

In my scenario I need forward get request to another end point. In my machine there are two servers php and node.js server. Node.js is like a "man in the middle", PHP server must work in the same way.

Node.js server code

```
var express = require('express');
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');
var http = require('http');
var https = require('https');
var app = express();

var HTTP_PORT = 3000;

// Create an HTTP service
http.createServer(app).listen(HTTP_PORT,function() {
  console.log('Listening HTTP on port ' + HTTP_PORT);
});


//endpoint for tracking
app.get('/track', function(req, res) {

  sendRequestToOtherEndPoint(req);

  processRequest(req);
  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
  res.send('Req OK');
});

function processRequest(req){
    console.log("request processed");
}

function sendRequestToOtherEndPoint(req){
    //magic here :)
}
```

When this server receive a get request in port 3000, it process request information and it must forward the same requesto to another end point.

For example:

1. Get localhost:3000/track?param1=1&param2=2
2. Server process get request
3. Server forward get request to localhost/final-endpoint?param1=1&param2=2

Comment: Do the first endpoint and the second one belong to different servers? I mean, as an example, the first one is part of the node.js code and the second one is part of the php code.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Depending on what you're trying to do, you can create a new request to the end-point:

```
//endpoint for tracking
app.get('/track', function(req, res) {

  req.get({url: 'http://end-point', headers: req.headers});

  processRequest(req);
  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
  res.send('Req OK');
});
```

More info: https://github.com/request/request

Comment: That is not what the 'get' method does according to the docs http://expressjs.com/en/5x/api.html#req.get

Answer (score 9):

There are a couple of useful libraries that one could use:

`http-proxy-middleware`:

```
const proxy = require('http-proxy-middleware')
var apiProxy = proxy('/track', {target: 'http://end-point'});
app.use(apiProxy)
```

`axios-express-proxy`

```
import express from 'express';
import { Proxy } from 'axios-express-proxy';
const app = express();
const port = 3000;

app.get('/track', (req, res) => Proxy('http://end-point', req, res));
```

Answer (score 2):

In you case `res.redirect` might help.

```
app.get('/track', function(req, res) {
   // process the request

   // then redirect
   res.redirect('/final-endpoint');
});
```

Then catch the redirected request in final endpont.

```
app.get('/final-endpoint', function(req, res) {
       // proceess redirected request here.
});
```

See the [Express docs](http://expressjs.com/api.html#res.redirect)

Comment: I think this is not the intended behavior, for a redirect is an hint for the client that is forced to perform another request to the new endpoint. Instead, I guess the target is to silently forward the request and send back the response, acting as a bridge.

Comment: I think it should be res.redirect?

Answer (score 1):

If your second endpoint is on a different server, (e.g. PHP) then you're going to need to either redirect the client (as in [sohel's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32141124/1590962)), or spoof a request from Node to the PHP server and then send the response back to the client. This latter option is definitely non-trivial so I would question whether it's crucial not to use a client redirect.

If you're talking about two express endpoints, then I think the simplest answer might be not to actually forward at all, but just use the endpoint callback directly instead:

```
app.get('/track', trackCallback);
app.get('/otherendpoint', otherendpointCallback);

function otherendpointCallback(req, res) {
  // do your thing
}

function trackCallback(req, res) {

  otherendpointCallback(req, res);

  processRequest(req);
  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
  res.send('Req OK');
};
```

Depending on exactly what you want to do at the other end point, you might need to spoof some of `req`'s fields (e.g. `req.url`)