# How to redirect with post request from server side?

Tags: node.js, express, pug

I am using express in one of my application. I want to make a post request to a url but it should also redirect to that url. Like when we submit a form using GET/POST method it redirect us to that url (). The only solution which is coming in my mind is

- make a hidden form
- redirect to that form from controller with data
- Submit form using js on page load.

The only disadvantage of this solution is user will see a black page for some time till the form gets loaded.

Can anyone suggest some better solution ?

Comment: So it's actually redirecting from client side ?

Comment: @gabriel-bleu Yes, redirecting from client side.

Comment: Question is how to redirect from server side ... what are you trying to do ?

Comment: @gabriel-bleu I know question is redirection from server side, but I am unable to find any such solution i.e. why I am using the above mentioned solution(client side ), If you know how to do the same then you can answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is not a "redirect." It's a solution which will send an extra request to another(or the same) URL and get the result from there instead of showing a blank page to the client for redirecting.

If that's correct, please refer to this similar question:[How to forward a request to other endpoint in node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32140987/how-to-forward-a-request-to-other-endpoint-in-node-js)

If you're looking for redirection (HTTP 301 & 302), the easiest way to do it is passing your data through `GET` URL query string. You can encrypt your data to prevent security risks.

Comment: I am looking for redirect, I want same behaviour when you submit an html form and it redirects you to that url along with data. I want the same from the server side.