# Node translation > client > node > json > node > client

Tags: json, node.js, ajax

I am not so good in node, need your help a little bit.

I want to make my node to be  'translator'. What does it mean?

I found something like this: 
[How to forward a request to other endpoint in node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32140987/how-to-forward-a-request-to-other-endpoint-in-node-js)

I want send through ajax request to my node server, then this server should send request to json and received data display in browser.

How can i change it to receive responses and throw it to browser?

```
var express = require('express');
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');
var http = require('http');
var https = require('https');
var app = express();

var HTTP_PORT = 3000;

// Create an HTTP service
http.createServer(app).listen(HTTP_PORT,function() {
  console.log('Listening HTTP on port ' + HTTP_PORT);
});


//endpoint for tracking
app.get('/track', function(req, res) {

  sendRequestToOtherEndPoint(req);

  processRequest(req);
  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
  res.send('Req OK');
});

function processRequest(req){
    console.log("request processed");
}

function sendRequestToOtherEndPoint(req){
    //magic here :)
}
```

I spend a lot of time on it and don't have ideas.

My ajax request:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#testbutton").click(function() {
        $.ajax({
url: '',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data) {
                $("#results").append('works');
                alert(data);
            },
             error: function() {
                $("#results").append("error");
                alert('error');
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

My actual server contains only

```
  request({
      url: ,
      method: "GET",
      timeout: 10000,
      followRedirect: true,
      maxRedirects: 10
  },function(error, response, body){
      if(!error && response.statusCode == 200){
          console.log('sucess!');
           console.log(response.body);
      }else{
          console.log('error' + response.body);
      }
```

and listen + some variables on start.

Answer (score -1):

So, the term you're looking for is "reverse proxy".  There are a lot of ways to do it, and a lot of potential gotchas, but if you don't want to make use of an existing module like [reverse-proxy](https://www.npmjs.com/package/reverse-proxy), then what you probably want to do is use the `request` module to [pipe the request and response streams](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request#streaming).  Something like this:

```
app.get('/proxy', (req, res) => {
  request('http://example.com/').pipe(res);
});
```