# Is it possible to build the independent service in Node JS?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, service

I'm new to Node JS.

I have a requirement like, I want to create a service in node js (like console app in .net), that service will fetch the data from mongodb and perform some analysis and insert analysis results into that database.
From the web application I want to execute that service and it should be run as independently in behind the screen (should not disturb the web application).

Is this possible in node js ?

I dont know above architecture/flow is make sense or not. Please share your suggestions.

Comment: `From the web application I want to execute that service` ? Create an endpoint, call it, forget about the response. Let it do it's thing.

Comment: @Bruce, What is an endpoint here, You mean create node service(API) and call it from web app right ? like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32140987/how-to-forward-a-request-to-other-endpoint-in-node-js

Comment: And I can create the services for analysis (referred from http://www.peachpit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2252193). I want to call the service from web app in response of the post. i.e. In Button click, I post the values to db and after posted the values to db, I want to call the service with the unique id as parameter which is get from the response of post.