# How to move from one route to other in node.js

Tags: node.js

I have form `post job.html` and a button **post**. I want that when someone submits this form the values save in database and then i get these values on another `helper's feed.html` page. Right now, my values are saving in database but i am unable to understand how to get those values in next page.

This is the part of html code for helpers feed.

```
<div class="col-md-10" > 
                    <div> Description:
                <input type="text" id="desc" name="budget"class="form-control">
                <div>
                <div> Category:
                     <input type="text" id="category" name="budget" class="form-control">
                </div>
                <div  > City:
                     <input type="text" id="city" name="budget" class="form-control">
                </div>
                <div > Budget
                     <input type="text" id="budget" name="budget" class="form-control">
                </div>
```

This is node.js file. post.js

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var path = require('path');
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host     : 'localhost',
    user     : 'root',
    password : 'sahoolat1',
    database : 'fyp_sahoolat'
});
connection.connect(function(err){
    if(err) throw err;
    console.log("connected");
});
var app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended : false}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.get('/', function(request, response) {
    response.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/job post.html'));
});

app.post('/post',(request,response,next)=>{
    var description=request.body.description;
    var contact_number=request.body.contact_number;
    var city=request.body.city;
    var budget=request.body.budget;
    var category=request.body.optradio;                    
   var query=connection.query("insert into jobs(Jobs_id,Description,Category,City,Contact_number,Budget) values(?,?,?,?,?,?)",[null,description,category,city,contact_number,budget],function(err){
        if(err)
            console.log(err);
        else
            console.log("moving");
            
        });
        next(); 
    });

app.get('/post',(request, response) => {
    connection.query("SELECT * FROM jobs",(err, result) => {
        if(err) {
            console.log(err);    
        }
        else { 
            console.log(result); 
            res.send(result); 
        }
    });
});

app.listen(3000);
```

The code runs fine till the line where i am saving in database and it prints "moving" on console.

[image]

I want to get each field value in the respective text fiels(as shown in screenshot)

Comment: you can see this below's solution:
[solution ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4062260/nodejs-redirect-url)

Comment: @MRanaHossain this is not what i am looking for

Comment: You'd either have to save the information to `localStorage` or perform a GET request on the next page

Comment: i am trying to get in the above code but its not working @Daniel_Knights

Comment: Which way do you want to do it? `localStorage` or another request?

Comment: @Daniel_Knights by using get request

Comment: Well it looks like you've already got a route setup for it so it just depends how your frontend is configured. Are you just using vanilla JS?

Comment: @Daniel_Knights I am using node.js for backend. Now i need a direction how to procedd and fulflll my requirement

Comment: You'd have to perform a request from your frontend once the page has changed.

Comment: Ok i will try :)

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32140987/how-to-forward-a-request-to-other-endpoint-in-node-js